# scroll bar not working properly in grid methode by tkinter gui in the display portion

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

m=Tk()

Label(m,text="name of product").grid(row=0)
Label(m,text="amount of ").grid(row=1)
Label(m,text="description of product").grid(row=2)

e1=Entry(m)
e2=Entry(m)
e3=Entry(m)

e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)
e3.grid(row=2,column=1)


def add(): 

global e1,e2,e3

file=open("daily_expense.txt","a")
file.write(e1.get())
file.write("\n")
file.write(e2.get())
file.write("\n")
file.write(e3.get())
file.write("\n")

e1.delete(0,END)
e2.delete(0,END)
e3.delete(0,END)
e1.focus()

file.close()

def display():  

file=open("daily_expense.txt","r")

Label(m,text=file.read()).grid(row=5,column=0)
#text=Text(file.read())
#text.grid(row=5,column=0)
file.close()

b1=Button(m,text="display",command=display).grid(row=4,column=0)
b=Button(m,text="add",command=add).grid(row=4,column=1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(m)
scrollbar.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky='ns')
display.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=display.yview)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello @Karan Singh. Please mention your problem in the description and not just type the code.

Comment: hi sir @PrajvalM actualy i am facing probelem of creating scroolbar in the display button as i am using this code scroll bar is created but not moving

Comment: Please edit your question describing the issue

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Also, you can't scroll widgets in a frame. You might want to read [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7432)